# ggplot2 lm lines with categorical variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some data from a R course class. The professor was adding each line kind of manually using base graphics. I'd like to do it using `ggplot2`.

So far I've created a `facet`'d plot in `ggplot` with `scatter plots` of `hunger` in different regions and also separately fitted a model to the data. The specific model has interaction terms between the `x` variable in the plot and the `group/colour` variable.

What I want to do now is **plot the lines resulting for that model one per panel**. I could do this by using `geom_abline` and defining the `slope` and the `intercept` as the sum of 2 of the coefficients (as the categorical variables for group have 0/1 values and in each panel only some values are multiplied by 1) - but this seems not easy.

I tried the same equation I used in lm in `stat_smooth` with no luck, I get an error.

Ideally, I'd think one can put the equation somehow into the `stat_smooth` and have `ggplot` do all the work. How would one go about it?

```
download.file("https://sparkpublic.s3.amazonaws.com/dataanalysis/hunger.csv", 
                  "hunger.csv", method = "curl")
hunger <- read.csv("hunger.csv")
hunger <- hunger[hunger$Sex!="Both sexes",]
hunger_small <- hunger[hunger$WHO.region!="WHO Non Members",c(5,6,8)]
q<- qplot(x = Year, y = Numeric, data = hunger_small, 
            color = WHO.region) + theme(legend.position = "bottom")
q <- q + facet_grid(.~WHO.region)+guides(col=guide_legend(nrow=2))
q

 # I could add the standard lm line from stat_smooth, but I dont want that
 #  q <- q + geom_smooth(method="lm",se=F)

#I want to add the line(s) from the lm fit below, it is really one line per panel
lmRegion <- lm(hunger$Numeric ~ hunger$Year + hunger$WHO.region + 
                  hunger$Year *hunger$WHO.region)

# I also used a loop to do it, as below, but all in one panel
# I am not able to do that
# with facets, I used a function I found to get the colors 

ggplotColours <- function(n=6, h=c(0, 360) +15) {
  if ((diff(h)%%360) < 1) h[2] <- h[2] - 360/n
  hcl(h = (seq(h[1], h[2], length = n)), c = 100, l = 65)
}

n <- length(levels(hunger_small$WHO.region))
q <- qplot(x = Year, y = Numeric, data = hunger_small, 
         color = WHO.region) + theme(legend.position = "bottom")
q <- q + geom_abline(intercept = lmRegion$coefficients[1], 
         slope = lmRegion$coefficients[2], color = ggplotColours(n=n)[1])
for (i in 2:n) {
  q <- q +  geom_abline(intercept = lmRegion$coefficients[1] + 
            lmRegion$coefficients[1+i], slope = lmRegion$coefficients[2] + 
              lmRegion$coefficients[7+i], color = ggplotColours(n=n)[i])
}
```

Comment: There is an approach [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549694/ggplot2-adding-regression-line-equation-and-r2-on-graph) that may be adaptable to a faceted graph.

Comment: for some reason (haven't figured it out yet) I couldn't reproduce your example (lines 2-n didn't show up on the plot). *However*: as far as I can tell the naive approach (`geom_smooth(method="lm",se=FALSE)`) *should* give you the same plot as you are looking for, with facets ...

Answer (score 0):

If you have one categorical data:

```
geom_point()
```

will not work,

```
geom_boxplot()
```

will work.

```
ggplot(hunger, aes(x = sex, y = hunger)) + geom_boxplot() + labs(x="sex") + geom_smooth(method = "lm",se=FALSE, col = "blue"). Susy
```